# Number of colours and Its shades of Html and CSS languages in total

Tags: html, css, colors

How many colours does the HTML and CSS has in total if we don't count the same colours and its shades? What's the exact number of overall colours number of these two languages?

Answer (score 0):

16777216

You can define the color's RGB values, each which go from 0-255